# Python - How does the FOR loop work in python

Tags: python

I have the following code in Python and I am an unsure about how the for loop here is working.

```
cur.execute("SELECT CUST_ID, COMPANY, LASTNAME, CITY, STATE FROM 
mytable")                            

colnames = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]
```

How does this for work ?

```
[desc[0] for desc in cur.description]
```

What is `desc[0`]?

Comment: `desc[0]` is the first element in `desc`.

Comment: the structure containing `desc[0]` is called a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 5):

Based on the code you've given us it seems like `desc` is an array itself and thus `colnames` is an array of all the `desc[0]` you get from each `desc` in `cur.description`

`desc[0]` is the first item in desc as arrays in Python are zero-indexed.

Comment: conn = db2.connect()                                                   
cur = conn.cursor()                                                    
                                                                       
cur.execute("SELECT CUST_ID, COMPANY, LASTNAME, CITY, STATE FROM  \    
    zendphp7.sp_cust WHERE COUNTRY = 'US'")                            
                                    
colnames = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]

Comment: cur.description is a LIST , and looks like Colnames is also list

Comment: You should put code edits in the main post. Regardless, your question has been answered.

Comment: Yes, and I have explained why it's a list above.

Answer (score 1):

It use iterable objects especially **next** methode it will consume the value inside the objects till get stop iteration, it works like a generator objects....

Comment: its not exactly clear to those unfamiliar with python where `next()` comes into play

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt of something, try to recreate the thing. Althought, it could be anything iterable, we could assume it's just a list, then:

```
description = [['first'], ['second', 'third'], [x, y, z], [...], ...]
colnames = [desc[0] for desc in description]
```

in the output you'll have:
`['first', 'second', x, ... ]`

Comment: why are we not getting "third" ?

Comment: @AJAY, `second` and `third` is in the same list, since we doing `desc[0]`, we getting `second`, that is, the first element. Notice that it is lists inside a list. `[ ['first'], ['second', 'third'], [...], ... ]`

Comment: Got it thanks, where can i find a good explanation on list in python

Comment: @AJAY, that's hard to tell, but typing python lists in google search will give you a huge number of websites that you can dig in. Here's some: Python Documentation for data structure => https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html and here's a random =>  https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list Try them.